# SwiftUI - Dismiss sheet to another view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to navigate to another View when sheet is dismissed, but not to the original

```
 @State var showOnboarding: Bool = false
 Button(action: {
                    self.showOnboarding.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Click me")

                }.sheet(isPresented: $showOnboarding) {

                    DiscoverView(showOnboarding: self.$showOnboarding)

                }
```

My question: It is possible to put something like .onDissapear{ NewView() } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you can use `onDismiss` to perform actions when a sheet is dismissed:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showOnboarding, onDismiss: {
    // on dismiss
    // here you can set some variables for presenting another sheet or navigating to some other views
}) {
    DiscoverView(showOnboarding: self.$showOnboarding)
}
```

You can present another View programmatically using a `NavigationLink` with an `isActive` parameter:

```
NavigationLink(destination: NewView(), isActive: $linkActive) {
    EmptyView()
}
```

Summing up your code can look like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showOnboarding: Bool = false
    @State var linkActive: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.showOnboarding.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Click me")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: NewView(), isActive: $linkActive) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showOnboarding, onDismiss: {
            self.linkActive = true
        }) {
            DiscoverView(showOnboarding: self.$showOnboarding)
        }
    }
}
```